# WorkSheet Name Exception?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am using infragestics.document.excel dll.

so I have created a Worksheet for the work book.

For Example:

```
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();


    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Analysis is Detailed Page Level Details");


    workbook.SetCurrentFormat(WorkbookFormat.Excel2007);
```

So in this am getting Exception Called Worksheet name should be between 1 to 31.

But I have to implement name as like in database so can any One give some solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

31 characters is the max limit for a Worksheet name. It's a hard limit, so there's no way around it. Pick shorter worksheet names.

Comment: YEs , Thanks For giving Solution Mr Tom.